retrieve pino logging json and save in variable
Is there any way to retrieve the pino log before it outputs to the console? For example if I have the following
import pino from 'pino';

// Create a logger instance
const logger = pino({
    level: 'info', // Set the log level
    prettyPrint: true, // Optional: Pretty print the logs
});

// Export the logger instance if you want to use it in other files
export default logger;

and then
logger.info("in function x"); 


I get the following in my console
{"level":20",timestamp":"2024-08-16T16:53:55.368Z","pid":26068,"hostname":"xxx","traceId":"ebacaa63-5cb6-47b5-8cb9-8f3600a8c35f","message":"in function x"}
is there any way for me to retrieve this log without writing it to a file (just storing the ouput of logger.info into a local variable?

You can capture the output of a Pino logger into variable and access it in your code using a custom stream.
import pino from "pino";
import { Writable } from "node:stream";

// This is the variable where the log message will be captured
const logs = [];

const customStream = new Writable({
    write(chunk, _encoding, callback) {
        logs.push(chunk.toString());
        callback();
    },
});

const logger = pino({ level: "info" }, customStream);

logger.info("This is a test log");
logger.error("This is an error");

console.log("Captured logs:", logs);


